# Short story: Ship's computer corrupted by crew epidemic of madness

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, spaceship, computers

This is a short story I read in an anthology - it feels like a 1960s or '70s story. Crew on a spaceship are going crazy due to a communicable disease and being locked in the brig/medical bay, with the ship's computer being a key help for the captain (the main character) as more and more crew are incapacitated.  But when the majority of the crew are insane, the computer switches sides, locking up the captain.

ETA: I believe that the ship's computer was programmed to be "normal" (in some sense) so "normal" changed (because the majority of the crew was unwell), it changed its behavior to conform.

Comment: I think I can see how that resolved itself. I also probably read it, but nothing's coming to me right now.

Comment: It feels like PK Dick or Sheckley maybe

Comment: It has a lot in common with George RR Martin's "Nightflyers". But there are enough differences that it's probably not it.